# Regex for matching a character, but not when it's enclosed in quotes

Tags: regex

I need to match a colon (':') in a string, but not when it's enclosed by quotes - either a " or ' character.

So the following should have 2 matches

```
something:'firstValue':'secondValue'
something:"firstValue":'secondValue'
```

but this should only have 1 match

```
something:'no:match'
```

Comment: @Jaco: 1) What language? 2) Isn't it way easier to split the string on ['"] first so you can check all uneven-numbered items in the array.

Comment: You would be better off with a parser.

Comment: @Gumbo...I guess that's what he want to achieve. My advise: Read byte-wise and use a flag if you're in quotes

Comment: You need to specify which regex implementation you will be using.

Comment: Although I have to agree with the others that it's actually harder to do this with a regex than with a simple scan.

Comment: This was in C#, but I thought the language was unimportant.  But I'm starting to think I would be better off with a parser like Gumbo said.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: [A regex to detect string not enclosed in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324749/a-regex-to-detect-string-not-enclosed-in-double-quotes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the regular expression implementation supports look-around assertions, try this:

```
:(?:(?<=["']:)|(?=["']))
```

This will match any colon that is either preceeded or followed by a double or single quote. So that does only consider construct like you mentioned. `something:firstValue` would not be matched.

It would be better if you build a little parser that reads the input byte-by-byte and remembers when quotation is open.

Comment: This works quite good, but fails in the degenerated case something:'no match:'

Comment: I agree with Gumbo - it's better to build a little parser

Comment: [See the regex in action on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bo4Es1/2).
I agree with @DanielBrückner, this regex works but fails in the mentioned degenerated case.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are stateless.  Tracking whether you are inside of quotes or not is state information.  It is, therefore, impossible to handle this correctly using only a single regular expression.  (Note that some "regular expression" implementations add extensions which may make this possible; I'm talking solely about "true" regular expressions here.)

Doing it with *two* regular expressions is possible, though, provided that you're willing to modify the original string or to work with a copy of it.  In Perl:

```
$string =~ s/['"][^'"]*['"]//g;
my $match_count = $string =~ /:/g;
```

The first will find every sequence consisting of a quote, followed by any number of non-quote characters, and terminated by a second quote, and remove all such sequences from the string.  This will eliminate any colons which are within quotes.  (`something:"firstValue":'secondValue'` becomes `something::` and `something:'no:match'` becomes `something:`)

The second does a simple count of the remaining colons, which will be those that weren't within quotes to start with.

Just counting the non-quoted colons doesn't seem like a particularly useful thing to do in most cases, though, so I suspect that your real goal is to split the string up into fields with colons as the field delimiter, in which case this regex-based solution is unsuitable, as it will destroy any data in quoted fields.  In that case, you need to use a real parser (most CSV parsers allow you to specify the delimiter and would be ideal for this) or, in the worst case, walk through the string character-by-character and split it manually.

If you tell us the language you're using, I'm sure somebody could suggest a good parser library for that language.

Comment: I'm using C# but I thought that I could do it with a Regex (which is language independent)... I think it's better to just parse it without Regex tho

Comment: That's the trouble; a regex isn't language/library independent; the parts that are can't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Uppps ... missed the point. Forget the rest. It's quite hard to do this because regex is not good at counting balanced characters (but the .NET implementation for example has an extension that can do it, but it's a bit complicated).

You can use negated character groups to do this.

```
[^'"]:[^'"]
```

You can further wrap the quotes in non-capturing groups.

```
(?:[^'"]):(?:[^'"])
```

Or you can use assertion.

```
(?<!['"]):(?!['"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the following slightly worrying construction:

`(?<=^('[^']*')*("[^"]*")*[^'"]*):`

It uses a lookbehind assertion to make sure you match an even number of quotes from the beginning of the line to the current colon. It allows for embedding a single quote inside double quotes and vice versa. As in:

`'a":b':c::"':"` (matches at positions 6, 8 and 9)

**EDIT**

Gumbo is right, using `*` within a look behind assertion is not allowed.

Comment: This expression will only match if the string starts with a single quote because of the assertion (?<=^('[^...

Comment: @Daniel - ('[^']*')* matches zero or more instances of something between single quotes, so it does not have to start with a quote. Having said that mine is broken to, see my edit

Comment: In general, look-behind assertions don’t allow infinite quantifiers such as `*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to catch the strings withing the quotes

`/(?<q>'|")([\w ]+)(\k<q>)/m`

First pattern defines the allowed quote types, second pattern takes all Word-Digits and spaces.
Very good on this solution is, it takes ONLY Strings where opening and closing quotes match.

[Try it at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YQgZQK/1)

Comment: I think this regex doesn't do what was asked for: split at colons except when they are within quoted parts.

Comment: It is not fully clear in the question, but my regex catches all colons. maybe it could be modified, if the question author wants to catch pieces without quotes too.