# A regex to detect string not enclosed in double quotes

Tags: regex

I have a string something like this

`"quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog`

I need a regex to detect words not enclosed in double quotes. After some random tries I found this `("([^"]+)")`. This detects a string enclosed in double quotes. But I want the opposite. I really can't come up with it even after trying to reverse the above mentioned regex. I am quite weak in regex. Please help me

Comment: you can match all strings, that a quoted with `"` and add `NOT` for this filter :)

Comment: so you want this to grab `fox jumps lazy dog` ?

Comment: okay, if you use `Perl`, you can use `$str!~/patternMatchesQuotedStrings/` - `NOT` filter for your word.

Comment: Related: [How to match something with regex that is not between two special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502598/3357935)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use lookahead/lookbehind assertions:

```
(?<![\S"])([^"\s]+)(?![\S"])
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> a='"quick" "brown" fox jumps "over" "the" lazy dog'
>>> print re.findall('(?<![\S"])([^"\s]+)(?![\S"])',a)
['fox', 'jumps', 'lazy', 'dog']
```

The main thing here is lookahead/lookbehind assertions. You can say: I want this symbol before the expression but I don't want it to be a part of the match itself. Ok. For that you use *assertions*:

```
(?<![\S"])abc
```

That is a *negative lookbehind*. That means you want `abc` but without `[\S"]` *before* it, that means there must be no non-space character (beginning of the word) or `"` before.

That is the same but in the other direction:

```
abc(?![\S"])
```

That is a *negative lookahead*. That means you want `abc` but without `[\S"]` *after* it.

There are four differenet assertions of the type in general:

```
(?=pattern)
    is a positive look-ahead assertion
(?!pattern)
    is a negative look-ahead assertion
(?<=pattern)
    is a positive look-behind assertion
(?<!pattern)
    is a negative look-behind assertion
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked like magic :)  Just one more favor, can you explain it a bit? Looks quite a bit complex

Comment: c'mon...you know their type as `lookahead/lookbehind assertions`. you can definitely explain me how that is working !!

Comment: does Python supports an Negation of regexps like `findAllExcept(/pattern/)`?

Comment: @loldop: what do you mean, "find all except"? you can use the same re but get not a list of strings but a list of indexes (something like: (a,b), (c,d) and so on) and then (0,a), (b,c), (d,-1) is what youa re looking for. right?

Comment: i mean, if i have simple condition, i will find all words, that DON'T match this condition

Comment: @IgorChubin , Can we improve this to exclude singlequoted strings as well?. I tried (?<![\\S\"[\\S']])([^\"\\s]+)(?![\\S\"[\\S']]) in vain.

Comment: @NishM: Why double brackets? Just write ["\']

Comment: The double quote seems redundant in `[\S"]` since non-space characters include `"`. This seems to do the same `(?<=\s)([^"\s]+)(?=\s)`.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex:

```
\s+(?<myword>([^\"\s]+)*)\s+
```

this should be work; and get group named *myword*. else you need to trim your result string.

Comment: that will not work for words with just one space between: `fox jumps` for example

Answer (score -3):

Remove the first quote from the string