# Convert comma-delimited CSV to pipe-delimited file with Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, delimiter

I have a comma-delimited CSV file (`,`) where commas are escaped by surrounding the data in quotation marks (`"`).

```
ID,Email,Job Title
1001,wdaelman@example.com,Technician
1002,rfewell@example.com,"Specialist, HRIT"
1003,jcoulbeck@example.com,"Director, Nursing"
```

I want to convert my CSV to a pipe-delimited file (`|`) by using Notepad++ to find and replace any commas that aren't enclosed in double quotes (`"`) with a pipe.

```
ID|Email|Job Title
1001|wdaelman@example.com|Technician
1002|rfewell@example.com|"Specialist, HRIT"
1003|jcoulbeck@example.com|"Director, Nursing"
```

My first approach was to use a regular expression to [match any unquoted commas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23641809/3357935).  However, searching for `("[^"]*")|,` in Notepad++ replaced both unquoted commas and any quoted strings that contained a comma.

```
1002|rfewell@example.com||
```

How can I convert a comma-delimited CSV file (`,`) to a pipe-delimited file (`|`) with Notepad++?

Answer (score 2):

You can use your regex, `("[^"]*")|,`, but you need to replace with `(?1$1:|)`.

The pattern matches and captures into Group 1 a `"`, then any 0+ chars other than `"` and then again a `"` (with `("[^"]*")`), or (`|`) just matches a comma (that is, a comma outside of double quoted substrings as those have already been matched with the preceding branch).

The `(?1$1:|)` replacement pattern means that once Group 1 matched (`(?1`) the Group 1 value should be put back where it was (see the `$1` placeholder), else (`:`) replace the matched string (i.e. the comma) with a pipe symbol.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to escape data with pipe characters? (IE: `1004,Special|HRIT` → `1004|"Special|HRIT"`)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Do you mean you want to wrap comma sepatated fields that contain `|` with double quotation marks? Try `([^,|\v]*\|[^,\v]*)|,` and replace with `(?1"$1":|)`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try with this:

1. Wrap data that has `|` character. First, replace: `,([^"\n,]*\|[^"\n,]*)` by `,"\1"`
2. Use `|` as delimiter: Replace: `,("[^"\n]*"|[^,\n]*)` by `|\1`

NOTE: I'm completelly ignoring first column, since It seems to be an ID that needs no extra processing