# dataframe how to split column by comma, but ignore those comma in double quotes

Tags: python, string, dataframe, split, strsplit

I have some questions about pandas dataframe reading csv file, and split column by comma.
I have a csv file with only 1 column(with multiple rows, and I have to split column by comma.

assume the  the dataframe is like
"a", "b", 2021-05-01 00:00:00,  "Tim, hortons"  with 4 comma splited, and 1 commna in string

I wanted it to be splited like a, b, 2021-05-01 00:00:00, Tim hortons in 4 columns

but when I use df[0].str.split(',', expand=True), it be comes

a, b, 2021-05-01 00:00:00, Tim, hortons   in 5 columns.

It did not ignore the comma between the double quote " ". Not all field are string type like the date, but all string are surround with ""

my code is like

In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(["a", "b", 2021-05-01 00:00:00, "Tim, hortons"])

with sftp.open(a) as f:

df = pd.DataFrame(f)

df = df[0].str.split(',', expand=True)

someone please help!!! its been bugging me for a long time. Thank you !!!!

Comment: Hi user3429999, please read how to make a [good and reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). It would help a lot if you could write the code that generates an example DataFrame with your issues, so that we can test quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to split the string by matching only comma not found between double quotes:

```
df[0].str.split(r',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*\Z)', expand=True)
```

Explanation of this regular expression can be found here: [How to match something with regex that is not between two special characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502598/how-to-match-something-with-regex-that-is-not-between-two-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import re
str_ = '"a", "b", 2021-05-01 00:00:00, "Tim, hortons"'
re.findall(r'(\d+|".*")', str_)
```

Output:

```
['"a", "b", 2021-05-01 00:00:00, "Tim, hortons"']
```

Then use .replace(',',' ') for replacing the comma in the last column(name) with space.

Answer (score 0):

```
myStr = '"aaaa,a","bb,bb","ccc,dd","test,str"'
commaSplitedValue = re.split(r',(?=")', myStr)

print(commaSplitedValue)
```

**Output**

```
['"aaaa,a"', '"bb,bb"', '"ccc,dd"', '"test,str"']
```