# Xpages - Full Text Search (>),! characters causing errors)

Tags: full-text-search, xpages, lotus-notes

my Xpages Full text search page crashes when using characters such as <(, and !. There are probably others too. My current solution has been to do something such as this, which blocks users from entering such characters.

```
var key;
if(window.event)
key=window.event.keyCode;
else
key=thisEvent.which

if (key==60) {
 thisEvent.preventDefault();
}
etc...
```

Iv'e searched, but could't find any documentation on how to submit a search string with these characters included. Is there any way to escape them?? or is this just a limitation of Lotus Notes.

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can search special characters in quotes.

The search term with `Hal!lo` will return "Query not understandable" error, because "!" means "NOT". But you can search `"Hal!lo"` and it will return what you want. But using quotes would be a problem in other cases. Suppose the user wants to search `XPages script` and if you put that query into quotes, it will search for an exact string.

So, I recommend either replacing those special characters with " AND " as Knut suggested, or enclose each word in the search term with quotes.

You might start with such an example: [A regex to detect string not enclosed in double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324749/a-regex-to-detect-string-not-enclosed-in-double-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Full text search in Notes Domino is **word** related. It divides the text into single words you can search for. The special characters you listed used as word delimiters. So, you can't search for them.

So, just replace special characters in the middle of a word with " AND " and omit them at the beginning and end of a word. This will search for the separated words. It might be that you get more search results then you would expect in first place as separated words could be anywhere in text and not just next to each other.

Example:

To find `<hal!lo>` you'd search for

```
hal AND lo
```

but not for `<hal!lo>` or `?hal lo?` or `hal*lo` or ...