# Extract JPA Named Parameters in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, hibernate, named-parameters, string-algorithm

I am trying to extract JPA named parameters in Javasacript. And this is the algorithm that I can think of

```js
const notStrRegex = /(?<![\S"'])([^"'\s]+)(?![\S"'])/gm
const namedParamCharsRegex = /[a-zA-Z0-9_]/;

/**
 * @returns array of named parameters which,
 * 1. always begins with :
 * 2. the remaining characters is guranteed to be following {@link namedParamCharsRegex}
 *
 * @example
 * 1. "select * from a where id = :myId3;" -> [':myId3']
 * 2. "to_timestamp_tz(:FROM_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SS')" -> [':FROM_DATE']
 * 3. "TO_CHAR(ep.CHANGEDT,'yyyy=mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')" -> []
 */
export function extractNamedParam(query: string): string[] {
  return (query.match(notStrRegex) ?? [])
    .filter((word) => word.includes(':'))
    .map((splittedWord) => splittedWord.substring(splittedWord.indexOf(':')))
    .filter((splittedWord) => splittedWord.length > 1) // ignore ":"
    .map((word) => {
      // i starts from 1 because word[0] is :
      for (let i = 1; i < word.length; i++) {
        const isAlphaNum = namedParamCharsRegex.test(word[i]);
        if (!isAlphaNum) return word.substring(0, i);
      }
      return word;
    });
}
```

I got inspired by the solution in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324894/12924700
to filter out all characters that are enclosed in single/double quotes.

While the code above fulfilled the 3 use cases above.
But when a user input

```js
const testStr  = '"user input invalid string \' :shouldIgnoreThisNamedParam \' in a string"'
extractNamedParam(testStr) // should return [] but it returns [":shouldIgnoreThisNamedParam"] instead
```

I did visit the source code of hibernate to see how named parameters are extracted there, but I couldn't find the algorithm that is doing the work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/"[^\\"]*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\"]*)*"|'[^\\']*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\']*)*'|(:\w+)/g
```

Get the Group 1 values only. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQMgfv/2/). The regex matches strings between single/double quotes and captures `:`  + one or more word chars in all other contexts.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const re = /"[^\\"]*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\"]*)*"|'[^\\']*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\']*)*'|(:\w+)/g;
const text = "to_timestamp_tz(:FROM_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SS')";
let matches=[], m;
while (m=re.exec(text)) {
  if (m[1]) {
    matches.push(m[1]);
  }
}
console.log(matches);
```

*Details*:

- `"[^\\"]*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\"]*)*"` - a `"`, then zero or more chars other than `"` and `\` (`[^"\\]*`), and then zero or more repetitions of any escaped char (`\\[\w\W]`) followed with zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`, and then a `"`
- `|` - or
- `'[^\\']*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\']*)*'` - a `'`, then zero or more chars other than `'` and `\` (`[^'\\]*`), and then zero or more repetitions of any escaped char (`\\[\w\W]`) followed with zero or more chars other than `'` and `\`, and then a `'`
- `|` - or
- `(:\w+)` - Group 1 (this is the value we need to get, the rest is just used to consume some text where matches must be ignored): a colon and one or more word chars.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works like a charm.

However, I would wish to understand how this regex works. With the help of explanation in _regex101_ and _mdn_ , I manage to understand that there are 3 alternatives here and we are only interested in the parenthesized substring match.

Can you please explain how alternative1/alternative2 regex works? i.e. `"[^\\"]*(?:\\[\w\W][^\\"]*)*"`