# regex match character but not within regex

Tags: java, regex

```
STOPATDESK YES;
:: TXT "LCLLMT:29.4700";
:: TXT "LCLCURR;NON-USD";
:: TXT "CALLBK:3";
:: TXT "FFTRL:EUR-LIM;-TAP-5";

STOPATDESK YES; :: TXT "LCLLMT:29.4700"; :: TXT "LCLCURR;NON-USD"; :: TXT "CALLBK:3"; :: TXT "FFTRL:EUR-LIM;-TAP-5";
```

Could you please provide regex that will match semicolons but not within TXT "..."?

There were several useful questions on StackOverflow but I failed to compile working solution for my case
[Regex for matching a character, but not when it's enclosed in square bracket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204657/regex-for-matching-a-character-but-not-when-its-enclosed-in-square-bracket)
[Regex for matching a character, but not when it's enclosed in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443360/regex-for-matching-a-character-but-not-when-its-enclosed-in-quotes)

Comment: I could not understand. Do you want to match the semicolons at the end of the lines?

Comment: there were several usefull questions on StackOverflow but I failed to compile working solution for my case

Comment: yes, I want to match semicollons but they may not be at the end of the lines

Comment: Just match? Easy: `"TEXT\\s*\"[^\"]*\"|(;)"` and grab `.group(1)`.

Comment: I want to use regex pattern in `String.split(String regex)`

Comment: look at Max;s answer. In case your semicolons can be found anywhere, it will be very difficult to match them with regex. Have a look at this regex tutorial if you need a more complex pattern: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-30-Minute-Regex-Tutorial

Comment: Try using [`s.split("(?<!TXT \"[^\"]{0,1000});")`](http://ideone.com/iXXCVc). If the `TXT "...` are not longer than 1000 symbols long, that might work in this case. But I do not think a constrained witdth look-behind is that reliable.

Answer (score 2):

You need a regex that matches any semicolon that is not followed by an odd number of quotes.

```
;(?![^"]*(([^"]*"[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)
```

The tricky part is to find the [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?![^"]*(([^"]*"[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*"[^"]*$)`:

- `[^"]*`  match any text before the first `"` after  `;`
- `(([^"]*"[^"]*"){2})*` match any even number of quotes with text inside
- `[^"]*"[^"]*$` match the last quote

If all the above conditions are matched, then an odd number of `"` is found after `;`. That implies that the `;` is inside two `"` and therefore it's not a valid `;`.

Regex: https://regex101.com/r/dG6cC1/1

Java demo: https://ideone.com/OuAaA5

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with:

```
"[^"]*"|(;)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mS2kJ0/2)

which will match quotes or separate semicolons, then get separate semicolons with `group(1)`. However the unbalanced quoting sings would couse a problem.
Or, if whole file is formated as your example (semicolons in quotation are preceded and followed by another character, not whitespace), you can try with:

```
;(?=\s|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pL8eA4/1)

It works with example above.